# Is there an ideal of $(C^0(\mathbb{R}),+,\cdot)$ that isn't prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $C^o(\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of continuous functions over $\mathbb{R}$ with multiplication and addition of functions.

What sort of ideals can exist in that ring apart from those that are caracterized by a root (for example all the funtions $f$ s.t. $f(3)=0$)

Is there an ideal that isn't prime?

I found the $I=\{f\in C^o(\mathbb{R})\ :\ f(x_1)=0$ and $f(x_2)=0\}$ if we take $f(x)=x-x_1$ and $g(x)=x-x_2$ we have that $fg\in I$ but $f\notin I$ and $g\notin I$

There is also $\langle p(x) \rangle$ where $p$ is a recucible polynomial in a ring of polynomials

Are there different examples?

Comment: You seem to have worked out for yourself some ideals that address the question posed in the title.  Since continuous real functions are not necessarily polynomials it is of course possible to construct examples of principal ideals which are "reducible" without having a polynomial generator.  Is that something that is of interest?

Comment: But what does it mean to be reducible in the space of continuous functions?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt Typically we do not use "reducible" outside of integral domains, so if you apply the definition directly things may break down.

Comment: I'm thinking of the space of continuous functions as a *ring*, so in that context an element is [reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) iff it can be expressed as the product of two non-units (a unit being an invertible ring element).

Comment: @rschwieb:  Nevertheless a principal ideal generated by a reducible element is never a prime ideal.

Comment: @hardmath True enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero ideal isn't prime, for example.

It's a well-known exercise (for example, Kaplansky's *Commutative rings* page 7 exercise #1, the first in the book) that for a commutative ring, having all proper ideals prime is equivalent to being a field.

Comment: The zero example is only the case if the ring is hase zero divisors right?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt No: $C^0(\mathbb R)$ has zero divisors. It doesn't have *nilpotent elements* if that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: isn't a nilpotent element a zero divisor?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt Of course it is. But obviously you can have zero divisors without having nilpotents, so that is not relevant.